# Can I make 'amortal' a word?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

I'm trying to contrast three types of mortality: "mortal", things which are living and temporary (humans); "immortal", things which maintain their existence through infinite lives (ideas); and "amortal", things which are not dependent on life to exist (machines).

'Amortal' is not technically a word; I was inspired by the use of 'astable' in an engineering context (https://english.stackexchange.com/a/134912/77833). Still, I find this comparison beautiful. Here's a sentence that attempts to incorporate all of them:

> While the **mortal** architects of society have proven its foundations unstable, the architects of the Internet have engineered an **immortal** feat of **amortal** stability.

Does "amortal" make sense in this context? Or, how might you rewrite this sentence with a similar comparison?

Comment: But surely *nothing* exists forever. Even the stable isotope of gold is subject to proton decay and has a half-life (very long, around 10³⁴ years, but not infinite).

Comment: @Andrew Leach "It is life, Jim, but not as we know it." A half-life and, say, human life, are different concepts. "Half-life uses "life" in a figurative sense.

Comment: I see no objection to coining "amortal" as a nonce word = *without, or lacking, mortality*, but the word for things like machines, toothpicks, and rock is "inanimate."

Comment: You **can** make up (or use in an unusual way) any word you please, as long as you make its intended meaning clear; whether doing so is going to be illuminating or distracting will be a matter of opinion, which will partially depend on the overall quality of your writing project.

Comment: The Amortal is also a short film and expanded character in various other media.

Comment: Yes, like **alingual**, for instance. Interesting that the system says that's a typo. **moral, immoral, amoral**, the same pattern.  [By the way, careful with all those "thes" in English; "Internet architects", no the.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for responding! You're right, I do like it without 'the'.

Comment: ...why would this question be closed now, years later, while e.g. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76374/instable-or-unstable remains open? Ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

**Amortal *is* a word.**

> **amortal** in British English
>
> (eɪˈmɔːtəl)
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> pursuing a lifestyle that defies the process of ageing
>
> Collins English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins Publishers
> https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/amortal

---

Note that Merriam-Webster has "amort" which with a little stretch could be made adjectival.

> Definition of amort archaic : being at the point of death
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amort

Comment: So the difference between _amortal_ and _immortal_ is that someone living an amortal lifestyle can (and will if they continue the amortal lifestyle long enough) succumb to infection, accident, homicide or warfare whereas an immortal can neither die naturally nor violently. I think the MW definition is a bit of a red herring since that seems to be the other 'a' prefix meaning 'on' or 'at' as in 'aboard', 'astern', 'athwart' and so on.

Comment: Note that _amort_ has a meaning greatly at odds with the meaning of _amortal_ in Collins. The full-length OED (1971) defines _amort_ as "In the state or act of death ; lifeless, inanimate ; _fig._ spiritless, dejected." Any adjective sense of _amortal_ built on the OED's definition of  of _amort_ would be very far from the meaning "not dependent on life to exist" that the poster wants to convey. The "a-" prefix is the core problem here, as it has multiple possible meanings. To reduce the range of possible interpretations, the poster might consider _nonmortal_ as an alternative to _amortal_.

Comment: [Nonmortal](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nonmortal) is already in some dictionaries meaning non-fatal, although it was my first thought as a possible answer to this question. (Mortal occasionally means fatal, as in "mortal wound".)